# APC Back-UPS and Corsair PSU do not work well together

Tags: power-supply, battery, sleep, ups

UPS: APC BX700U-GR

PSU: Corsair RM550X

Maximum power consumption of all devices connected to the UPS: 100-110W

Average power consumption of all devices connected to the UPS: 60-70W

It is not possible to wake the computer from sleep mode when the AC power is off. It is also not possible to start the computer on battery power alone. If the computer is fully on during a power outage, all is well, it is running on battery power. When attempting to power on or wake up from battery power, a brief buzzing sound is heard. When attempting to wake up from sleep mode, the computer switches off completely; when mains power is restored, the computer performs a full boot. All other devices work without problems on battery power.

I have tried changing the sensitivity of the UPS, without success.

Can such problems damage the PSU? Should I still use this UPS or is it better not to?

Comment: Maybe there's a bad interaction between the UPS' stepped sine wave output and the PSU's power factor correction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The manufacturer has replaced the unit under warranty with a newer model BX750MI-GR (BX700U-GR has been discontinued). At the moment everything works correctly, I can turn on or wake up the computer on battery power without any problem.